# missing-syscalls error during linux kernel 2.6 compilation

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, linux-kernel

i am trying to experiment with linux kernel by adding a custom system call into the kernel.I succeeded at first and later I made some modifications to the file containing the new call code and when i tried to recompile the kernel with

> make bzImage

i get the the following error:

[image]

What seems to be the reason for the error?

Comment: If you roll back your modifications can make find the missing target?

Answer (score 0):

Your syscal module dependecies cannot be compiled because of code changes in your custom code